# Obtain a 16 character string from a 32 character string

Tags: hash, md5

How do i obtain a string that is 16 characters long, from a string that is 32 characters long.
This 32 character string is a md5 hash. So how do i get the obtained 16 character string to be reasonably unique as well?
I need to generate about 1,00,000 such strings a month. And I need to ensure that all strings generated are unique across all runs.

Comment: umm... take every other character?

Comment: read about collisions, i suggest it's not an option for you to do what you wrote. You may just generate 16-character key by yourself. like making a string with available characters, then str_shuffle and substing first 16 characters. Just an idea.

Comment: Does it need to be reversible? Is this a compression algorithm or another hashing algorithm? You say it must be "reasonably unique" but there are already collisions present in md5. I suppose by reasonably unique, you just mean... unlikely to be the same as something else?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be to take every other character.

For example,

```
ipm98u2nm0c87ne0p87n87bnvjckp97w ->
im82mc7ep78bvcp7
```

This would probably be the best way you could keep it as unique as possible, but the problem with removing characters, as pointed out in [Gray's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984544/obtain-a-16-character-string-from-a-32-character-string/16984630?noredirect=1#comment24535656_16984630), is that when you remove a character, you actually divide the amount of unique strings by 36 (or however many possible characters there are).

Comment: I kinda want to dispute that "2 times" figure, but I am not good enough at statistics to know how. Just for example, going from "ipm" to "im" creates the possibility for iam, ibm, icm, etc. It seems like your chances of a collision increase exponentially, not linearly. Maybe someone who knows better than me can confirm/dispute?

Comment: @Gray Hm, that is a good point. When you remove a character you actually divide the amount of possibilities by the amount of characters used. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: If i had to generate around 1,00,000 16-character strings a month, the probability of a collision will still be pretty low, right? Or is the solution by @zaq178miami a better proposition?

Answer (score 0):

I will explain my original comment. If your unique key doesn't depend on some data use UUID or as i said:

```
$string = str_shuffle('abcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890');
$uniqe = substr($string, 0, 16);

var_dump($uniqe);
```

If your unique key should depend on any data and should be exactly 1 chars long use other hashing algorithms which produce 64 value. For list of hashing algorithms look [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions)